# django, upload tif image

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to upload a tif image (greyscale), using django ImageField.
I have installed Pillow==8.3.1 and using Python 3.9.
The app works only with PNG/JPEG images.

Here is the model I am using:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        #breakpoint()
    # def __str__(self):
    #     pixels = tfi.imread(self.image)
    #     return np.shape(np.array(pixels))
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #open image
        #breakpoint()
        if self.action=='tif':
            pixels = tfi.imread(self.image)
        else:
            pixels = Image.open(self.image)
       
        #pixels = tfi.imread(self.image)
        pixels = np.array(pixels)
        pixels=pixels[:,:,0]
        #pixels = pixels[0,:,:]
        #use the normalisation method
        img = get_image(pixels)
        im_pil=Image.fromarray(img)
        #save
        buffer = BytesIO()
        im_pil.save(buffer,format='png')
        image_png = buffer.getvalue()
        self.image.save(str(self.image), ContentFile(image_png),save=False)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        #return self.image_png
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's ImageField requires the third-party package Pillow. It depends on the pillow to verify that a file is indeed an image or not. This is not dependant on the file type, but on the content of the file itself.
please check your version of pillow you are using, and check the corresponding documentation of your pillow version.

https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

[supported image format by pillow 8.3.1](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#:%7E:text=Pillow%20reads%20JPEG%2C%20JFIF%2C%20and,standard%20and%20progressive%20JFIF%20files.)

but if still something doesn't work for you you can always use FileField which doesn't look for what file or format u are uploading until u are uploading a file please check out documentation

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filefield-django-models/

Although I would recommend you to use imagefield for only image and read the documentation now it totally up to you what you want to use.